# Compute the probability of a uniform and continuous random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem:

$X$ is a continuous and uniform random variable in $(0, 2\pi)$. Compute the average, the variance and the $P(X> 0.5 \pi | X>0.5)$

I have computed the average ($E[X]= \pi$) and the variance ($Var[X]= \frac{1}{3} \pi^2 = 3.290$). How can I compute the probability requested in the exercise?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of conditional probability,

$P(X > 0.5\pi \mid X> 0.5) = \cfrac{P(X> 0.5\pi \bigcap X> 0.5)}{P(X>0.5)}$

Note that if $X>0.5\pi$ then $X$ must be greater than $0.5$ because $0.5\pi > 0.5$. Thus the above probability becomes

$\cfrac{P(X>0.5\pi)}{P(X>0.5)}$

Do you know how to finish from here?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help... my problem is find $P(X> 0.5 \pi)$ and $P(X> 0.5)$ Are two integrals beacuse the random variable is continue?

Comment: Yup! $P(X>0.5\pi) = \int_{0.5\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) \text dx$ and $P(X>0.5) = \int_{0.5}^{2\pi} f(x) \text dx$, where $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$. Do you know the probability density function for a uniform random variable?

Comment: $\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{2\pi-0}$ ?? I hope to give the right answer

Comment: Yup that's right. @BigBoy

Comment: Thanks bro, you have a paied pizza from me :D I check your answer like best answer

Comment: Is the result right? $P(X>0.5 \pi | X>0.5)=\frac{3 \pi}{4 \pi - 1}$

Comment: @BigBoy Yes it is!

Comment: Thanks @jeremy909